# Extract date from long complicated date plus time stamp?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am using bootstrap calendar and on clicking any particular date I got complicated date in this form:

```
Sat Sep 06 2014 00:00:00 GMT 0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
```

Can anybody please tell me how I can extract only date from this complicated long date?

I am working in PHP codeignitor, is there any way in PHP or JavaScript through which I can only extract date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is for Javascript then just use this:

```
var myDate = new Date('Sat Sep 06 2014 00:00:00 GMT 0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)');
```

after that you can use `myDate` as a date object and call its methods like `myDate.getFullYear()` etc.

Comment: can you please elaborate i have this complicated date in javascript variable date

Comment: yes it worked correct i extracted all fields separately all merged all of them.thanks